# Windows Explorer not displaying drives (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

A very strange issue - Windows Explorer doesn't display the drives connected to my machine.  I *did* make some changes to my setup a while back with the **Local Group Policy Editor** to disable the "Aero Shake" behavior, so I may have inadvertently enabled or disabled something related to this, but to be honest, I don't remember when the behavior actually started.

Any ideas?  This is a Windows 7 machine.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have accidentally hid your drives. Check [this](http://www.dkszone.net/how-to-hide-drives-in-my-computer-of) out.

Comment: Just tried this, and a couple of related settings in the Policy Editor - nothing seems to change.  For what it's worth, the sidebar in explorer isn't displaying the **computer** icon either.

Comment: Ok, definitely accepting this as the right answer :) Once I opened up the **Policy Editor** again I noticed that there was an **All Settings** node in the tree.  After selecting that, I was able to sort the settings by **State** to see everything that I've enabled/disabled.  I reverted all the settings except for the Aero Shake, and now it's working!  Thanks again.

Comment: Great :) Glad you fixed it.